# HERE Routing API V8: How to get route with multiple pass through waypoints

Tags: here-api

In v7, this is the way of getting route with multiple passthrough waypoints:

https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=32.353514,-61.126775&waypoint1=passThrough!32.365181,-61.102086&waypoint2=32.360273,-61.091979&mode=fastest;pedestrian...

In v8 api reference, there's "via" which seems to be used for stop over waypoints.

I tried https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=pedestrian&return=summary,polyline,actions,instructions&origin=42.353514,-71.126775;42.365181,-71.102086&destination=42.360273,-71.091979&via=42.365181,-71.102086..

It's generating 2 legs ("section" in v8 definition) in the route. I'm expecting 1 leg.

This [v8 developer guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/waypoint.html) page mentioned passThrough:

> Waypoints may represent stopover points (that is, points where some time will be spent before retaking the route), or passthrough points that only influence the route's shape, but where no actual stop is carried out.

But I wasn't able to figure out how to query a route with multiple pass through points in v8.

Any advice?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if returning 2 sections instead of one in V8 is an issue.

Regarding the passthrough point, it's described in [API reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/api-reference-swagger.html) as `WaypointOptions` for query parameter `via`:

```
Supported waypoint options:

- stopDuration: desired duration for the stop, in seconds.
```

So I assume that all requests treat `via` parameter without option `stopDuration`   as passthrough point. But you always can add `!stopDuration=0` to be 100% sure.

This request (with stopDuration=0 or without this option) https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&return=travelSummary,summary,polyline,actions&origin=42.353514,-71.126775&destination=42.360273,-71.091979&via=42.365181,-71.102086!stopDuration=0&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY

returns summary:

```
"summary": {
  "duration": 714,
  "length": 3893,
  "baseDuration": 637
}
```

and this request with stopDuration=900 
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&return=travelSummary,summary,polyline,actions&origin=42.353514,-71.126775&destination=42.360273,-71.091979&via=42.365181,-71.102086!stopDuration=900&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY

returns summary:

```
"summary": {
  "duration": 714,
  "length": 3893,
  "baseDuration": 1537
}
```

As you can see `baseDuration` was increased  by 900 as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative option to solve this type of problem you can sent the two request.

For example : A-->B
              B-->C
You pass the request like this

First request A-->B

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=pedestrian&return=summary,polyline,actions,instructions&origin=42.353514,-71.126775;42.365181,-71.102086&destination=42.365181,-71.102086
```

Second request B-->C

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=pedestrian&return=summary,polyline,actions,instructions&origin=42.365181,-71.102086&destination=42.360273,-71.091979
enter code here
```

Now add the result of both, you will get the desired distance and time.