# How to add the stopover in here map api request between start and destination

Tags: api, postman, here-api

I want to include the the stop over between the start and destination, So route should be calculate like
`start-->waypoints-->destination`.

This is the api request of heremap:

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&origin=36.15033,-115.111499&destination=36.155825,-115.145881&via:36.171873,-115.146747&return=summary&apiKey=<apiKey>
```

But route calculates between origin and destination only, it avoid the via co-ordinates

Comment: If we add the via: parameter it does not affect the result. See this below question for more clarification.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61513987/here-routing-api-v8-how-to-get-route-with-multiple-pass-through-waypoints/61713545#61713545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your request.

Use `via=` instead of `via:`

`https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&origin=36.15033,-115.111499&via=36.171873,-115.146747&destination=36.155825,-115.145881&return=summary,polyline&apiKey=`