# HERE Routing API V8: Waypoint options broken?

Tags: here-api

Place options (lat,long;key=value) work, but can't get waypoint options to work (lat,long!key=value). Have tried using browser, cUrl and Postman so quite sure it's not an issue of encoding/escaping

Neither can I get any of these examples to work
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61533651/14060534

For example:
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&return=travelSummary,summary,polyline,actions&origin=32.6289624435649,35.079885159610136&destination=32.0155,34.7505&via=32.119485,34.938341!stopDuration=0&apikey=KEY
doesnt work

but
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&return=travelSummary,summary,polyline,actions&origin=32.6289624435649,35.079885159610136&destination=32.0155,34.7505&via=32.119485,34.938341;course=60&apikey=KEY
is fine

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing this out. I will take this up with the product team and get it fixed.